# ActiveMQ, Network of brokers, offline durable subscriber dedupe

Tags: activemq-classic

**Scenario:** Two ActiveMQ nodes A, B. No master slave, but peers, with network connectors between them.

A durable topic subscriber is registered with both (as it uses failover and at one point connects to A and at another point connects to B).

**Issue:** If subscriber is being online against A, a copy of each message is placed in the offload subscription on B.

**Question:** Is this by design? Can this be configured so that a message is deduped and only sent to the subscriber in one of subscriptions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently *by-design*: http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-distributed-queues-work.html

See "Distributed Topics in Store/Forward" where it says:

> For topics the above algorithm is followed except, every interested client receives a copy of the message - plus ActiveMQ will check for loops (to avoid a message flowing infinitely around a ring of brokers).